# Elasticsearch: Does Composite aggregation support minimum doc count filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) support min_doc_count filter?

I want to only return aggregations those have min_doc_count 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`min_doc_count` is not supported by the `composite` aggregation and according to [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32452) it doesn't seem like it will ever be the case.

You can achieve the `min_doc_count` functionality by paginating all buckets and doing it on the client side.

Comment: Thanks! .. I was going through the same thread  and was about to answer :)